# phpMyAdmin -- how do I figure out which DB these connections and processes belong to?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I've got about 8 databases on one server, mostly corresponding to WordPress sites. I'm using shared hosting that does not give us superuser permissions. When I log into phpMyAdmin (version 3.5.2) and head to the Status -> Monitor tab, I see more connections open at any given time than I might expect. What I want to do is figure out which sites/databases are causing this to happen.

Google brought me to the "show full processlist" command, but my understanding is that it's not actually going to help unless I have superuser permissions, which I do not have. The command *does* run, but it doesn't come back with any information. I saw that there were also general and "slow query" logs, but again that seems like something I can't actually access with the current user permissions. Given that, it actually seems a little odd to me that it shows me as much as it does on the "status" pages. I'm just not technically proficient enough to be able to parse anything meaningful out of what's there.

Perhaps the better route is to search for a way to track this from the WordPress end of things?

Bear in mind that I'm very new to the world of administrating databases when replying. Thanks!

[image: Connections / processes graph]

Comment: *unless I have superuser permissions* Only PROCESS privilege needed to see ALL processes, otherwise you'll see your connections only. But does you're interested in ALL processes, do you think that somebody else accesses your databases? You may ask your hosting to add this privilege (maybe temporarily) to your account - showing all processes in processlist is the only additional right provided by it.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: See if this provides the info:  `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;`